# Python - check if array is empty

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of two int's, and I want to check if either is None, so I have this:

```
print hourArray
if hourArray[0] or hourArray[1] is None:
    print "FAILED???"
else:
    print "array is full"
```

And even though the `print hourArray` shows this right before the if statement

```
[2040, 2640]
```

It prints `FAILED???` even though neither of the elements in the array is None?

Why is this happening?

Comment: `if (hourArray[0] is None) or (hourArray[1] is None)` or `if None in [hourArray[0], hourArray[1]]`

Comment: `if a or b == something` is an incredibly common mistake in Python, see the duplicate. Firstly it should be `if a == something or b == something`. Secondly you should use `==` instead of `is`

Comment: @CoryKramer Comparing to singletons like `None` should be done with `is` in python, according to [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are checking `if (hourArray[0]) or (hourArray[1] is None)` , all non-zero integer values are always true.

You should do -

```
if hourArray[0] is None or hourArray[1] is None:
```

Example of non-zero integer values being true -

```
>>> if 1:
...     print('Hello')
...
Hello
```

Comment: Fixed, sorry missed that.